# Is there a way to convert void *buf to a char?

Tags: c, char, void

I'm using the read function to take in one character, then running the read function again.  Before I run the function again, I want to save what's in the buffer to a char variable.  Like this:

```
void *buf;
read(0,buf,1);
char tempChar;
```

I want to store what's in *buf into the char tempChar.  I know I can't just set them equal, but is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
char tempChar;
read(0,&tempChar,1);
```

So there's actually no need to have a separate buffer at all.

Comment: As an aside, one of the first thing OP (or anyone new to C) needs to get used to about pointers is that when a function takes a pointer as an argument, that does **not** mean you need a pointer variable in the caller. In many cases, you simply want to pass the address of an existing local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can `tempChar = *(char *)buf;` if an extra buffer is required.